# Rotating of a system of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, orbital-motion

In basic physics lectures, the teacher or professor in my class never explains the behavior of rotating two or many body particles. In my experience and intuition doing physics, two-particle or many-body systems tend to rotate about their center of mass. For example, the earth-sun rotates around its center of mass, or two black holes rotate around its center of mass; also in ideal conditions, without air friction, a stick when a force is applied to it at the end edge, stick will rotate around its center of mass. Can anyone explain the physics of a system of mass that tends to rotate around its center of mass?
I tried to solve this problem and read some reference books, but I don't have any conclusion. most of the books I read just explain what rotation or torque is.

Or, is my intuition wrong?

Comment: It's unclear what's your exact question.

Comment: Hi Dika and welcome to the Physics SE. The centre of mass cannot move unless an external force is applied because this would violate conservation of momentum. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas I am observing that most two-body systems or many-body systems tend to move to rotate about their center of mass, eg: planet-sun, two neutron stars, or when a stick standing on a frictionless floor will rotate about its center of mass if there is an external force applied to it. I just wondered why they behaved like that. Why does a system of mass tend to rotate about its center of mass if an external force applied?

Comment: @JohnRennie  I am observing that most two-body systems or many-body systems tend to move to rotate about their center of mass, eg: planet-sun, two neutron stars, or when a stick standing on a frictionless floor will rotate about its center of mass if there is an external force applied to it. I just wondered why they behaved like that. Why does a system of mass tend to rotate about its center of mass if an external force applied?

Comment: @Dika Are you effectively wondering why systems aren't rotating "naturally" around any other pivot point, except COM ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas yeah. it is also my question in mind, why not other pivot points? why the center of mass?

Comment: For system to rotate about any pivot point, except COM,- external torque must be applied. While systems can rotate about their COM, solely due to conservation of angular momentum. Or in other words due to Newton first law applied to angular motion. So to say systems rotate around COM due to angular inertia. While _change_ in this angular speed must be given by force, gravity, electrostatics, convection of dust+gases (in case of first impulse to "pre-galaxy" disk rotation start), etc. Or we can say that everybody and everything saves internal energy. For other pivots you need energy supply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can understand this question intuitively like this:
The motion of the centre of mass is only dependent on external force on the entire system. Therefore if there is no external force, the centre of mass will remain static. Thus, the system ratates around the centre of mass if there is no external force on the system.
If there is a fixed pivot for rigid body, the pivot itself will provide external force on the body, so that the body might not rotate around its centre of mass anymore.

I will prove this on a rigid two particle system using knowledge of circular motion

let's consider a system of two particles, m1 and m2, connected by a massless rod/string. The system is rotating with an angular speed of $ \omega\ $, and the length of the string is L, and the center of rotation (pivot) is located at a distance x to m1.[image]

it is the tension of the srting that provides the centripital force two particles need to do circular motion. Note that the centripital force is the same for m1 and m2, since they are connected by a string, or, you can justify this by saying there is no external force acting on the system.
The equation of the centripital forces of the two particles are expressed as followed:
$$
m_{1}\omega^{2}x=m_2\omega^{2}\left(L-x\right)
$$
x can be solved as:
$$
x=\dfrac{m_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}\cdot L
$$

The one dimensional location of a  centre of mass of a system is expressed as
$$
x_{cm}=\dfrac{\sum m_{i}\cdot r_{i}}{\sum m_{i}}
$$
in our specific case, $x_{cm}$ is
$$
x_{cm}=\dfrac{m_{1}\cdot 0+m_{2}\cdot L}{m_{1}+m_{2}}=\dfrac{m_{1}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}L
$$
Therefore, $x_{cm}=x$ so the centre of rotation is actually the centre of mass.

Comment: your analogy really help me to understand my question in mind. Your explanation is very clear and intuitive.